# Storing user language as Claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims

In an ASP.NET MVC app I'm developing I thought I could store the user language as a Claim so I don't have to access the database or deal with session. Is there any drawback to this?

Comment: I'd say using claims for that is bang-on. It is in the cookie, it is available on every request, no db-requests and fast. Drawbacks? have not found so far. As long as you don't go mad with claims and don't add a million of them to over-blow the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user language can not be changed by user through the application, I don't see any major drawbacks here.
As an opposite if user can modify it's language in your application you will have to refresh your authentication token - and this is something you should consider.

Another drawback is, the more claims you add to the token, the bigger it be but in this case it is really negligible.

By the way, why are you against sessions(i think using it here isn't that bad...)?

Comment: When the user changes it's language I logout and login again to recreate the cookie. Also, I'm not really against using session, but I have to take care to reset the session variable when the user logs out and some other things that I didn't like in this situation.

Comment: Is there any additional reason for doing it or it is only for the language ?

Comment: For now it's for translations. I'll need to change UICulture and so on in a following iteration...

Comment: You can use authentication token as a session key this way each time the user logs in he will have a new session...

Comment: Well it is your call here...I can say that we developed multitenant, localized, large scale web application and we were storing this kind of data in session - so far there were no issues with this approach in our case.

Comment: After reading this, I stopped using sessions: http://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/